# CodeIgniter PHP - How to randomly select a language class message?

Tags: php, codeigniter, random

The idea here is to have a series of tips in application/language/english/tips_lang.php

```
$lang['tip1'] = 'Water your plants';
$lang['tip2'] = 'Aerate your soil';
$lang['tip3'] = 'Use ventilation';
$lang['tip4'] = 'Fertilizers are good';

etc...
```

In my controller I would like to have something like this pseudo-code

```
$input = $this->lang->line('tip_array');

$tip = array_rand($input, 1);
```

Anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks for giving a hand!

UPDATE controller

```
        //Random Tip
        $array = explode('|', $this->lang->line('tips'));
        $tips = array_rand($array, 1);
        $this->template->write('tips', $tips);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeIgniter doesn't support n-dimensional arrays for the language files, but you can work around that:

```
$lang['tips'] = 'Water your plants|Aerate your soil|Use ventilation|Fertilizers are good';
```

Or, if you preffer to have them one on each line:

```
$lang['tips'] = array();
$lang['tips'][] = 'Water your plants';
$lang['tips'][] = 'Aerate your soil';
$lang['tips'][] = 'Use ventilation';
$lang['tips'][] = 'Fertilizers are good';
$lang['tips'] = implode('|', $lang['tips']);
```

---

> **/controllers/yourController.php:**

```
$tips = explode('|', $this->lang->line('tips'));

echo $tips[array_rand($tips, 1)];
```

---

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks @alix - not sure what to do with the `$language` in the last line of code - it generates an error

Comment: @torr: Sorry, it was a typo - fixed it!

Comment: ;) - OK - this now works but in an interesting way - i do get random lines echo'd to my view, but they are ALSO from another lang file in the same folder. I am using autoload for the tip lang file and this other lang file. could that be the problem?

Comment: @torr: I checked and seems like CI merges **all** language entries in `$this->lang->language`, which is pretty lame for us. Check my updated solution, maybe it suffices?

Comment: @alix - almost there - please see the code I am using for my controller on the OP (i am using your mulit-line array suggesttion in lang) - what I get with that are random KEYS sent to my view, not the values - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @torr: `array_rand()` picks keys, not values. Try this: `$this->template->write('tips', $array[$tips]);`.